# why does windows 10 shows 4 languaje inputs for the keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, language

I have removed all languages except for Latin American (Perú) but the keyboard layout shows 4 inputs:

1. Spanish (Peru) Latin american keyboard
2. Spanish (Peru) US keyboard
3. English (US) US keyboard
4. English (US) US keyboard - International

I've already deleted the input layout from `regedit`, but after deleting any of the they do not disappear. And after restarting the PC they appear again.

If anyone knows what I can do to maintain at last only two inputs (1 & 2) or knows why is it that there are 4 inputs when i only set  one language, i'd be really thankfull.

Comment: Why are you removing keyboard layouts with regedit.  You should be using the Settings UWP application to remove keyboard layouts.

Comment: I tried to find info about the issue and all I found was to remove the keyboard layouts in regedit because apparently windows adds these layouts for some reason.

Comment: They added them because a user added them.  Remove the layouts through the Settings UWP application